# Error while launch the emulator on Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, nullpointerexception

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference
```

This is in MainActivity:

```
 ContextWrapper bandContextWrapper = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext()) {
        @Override public boolean bindService(Intent service, ServiceConnection conn, int flags) {
            final String action = service.getAction();
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(action) && action.startsWith("com.microsoft.kapp")) {
                //service.setPackage("com.microsoft.band");
                service.setPackage("com.microsoft.kapp");
            }
            return super.bindService(service, conn, flags);
        }
    };
```

This is in OnClickListener of Button:

```
bandClient = BandClientManager.getInstance().create(bandContextWrapper, pairedBands[0]);
```

This where it is initialized:

private View.OnClickListener btnSyncClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View button) {

        try {
            pairedBands = BandClientManager.getInstance().getPairedBands();
            bandClient = BandClientManager.getInstance().create(bandContextWrapper, pairedBands[0]);

          new ConnectTask().execute();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            tvBandStatusMessage.setText("Could not connect");
        }
    }
};
```

Button is initialized in OnCreate

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    ImageView b = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.btnSync);
    b.setOnClickListener(btnSyncClickListener);
```

}

I see this error when I launch the emulator. I'm using Android Studio!

Comment: Where are you instantiating this bandContextWrapper ? You need to show where in MainActivity you instantiate this

Comment: Please post complete log cat trace and also specify which line is giving you the error.